# Validate number values using hibernate validator

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Now, I am developing a web application with Spring MVC.

And in my project, I try to use **HIBERNATE VALIDATOR** for form validation.

In a table of database for my project, the following field is included.

```
[rate] numeric(5,2)
```

So, I want to add a validation for that field, and I declare field **in my bean as follow**:

```
private double rate;
```

But, I don't know how to validate the value of the field using hibernate validator.

So, I try to get help from GOOGLE, but I don't get **a good solution** for my problem.

The sample values can be **"0.05", "1.00", "12.55"**, etc.

Therefore, if any way to solve this problem, please light-up me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`@Digits`** annotation as follow:

```
@Digits(integer=5, fraction=2)
@Column(name = "rate")
private BigDecimal rate;
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Yes, I tried with your code. But when I input **`abc`** values to **`rate`** field, it shown **`Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.math.BigDecimal] `** error. Is any other option, please? Thanks.